# Property 'TextInput' doesn't exist in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native

Trying to set up a login screen for a social media app that I'm building and have a LoginScreen.js and a RegisterScreen.js with forms for email and password, but whenever I try to render I get a Render Error telling me that "Property 'TextInput' doesn't exist".

Here is my code for LoginScreen.js; RegisterScreen.js is modelled similarly.

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import { signInWithEmailAndPassword } from 'firebase/auth';
import {initializeApp} from 'firebase/app';
import {getAnalytics} from 'firebase/analytics';
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth';

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {
    [hidden]
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth(app);
export default class LoginScreen extends React.Component {
    state = {
        email: "",
        password: "",
        errorMessage: null
    }

    handleLogin = () => {
        const {email, password} = this.state

        signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
            .catch(error => this.setState({errorMessage: error.message}))
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text style={styles.greeting}>
                {'Hello again. \nWelcome back.'}
                </Text>

                <View style={styles.errorMessage}>
                    {this.state.errorMessage && <Text style={styles.error}>{this.state.errorMessage}</Text>}
                </View>

                <View style={styles.form}>
                    <View>
                        <TextInput
                            style={styles.input}
                            autoCapitalize="none"
                            placeholder="Email address"
                            onChangeText={email => this.setState({email})}
                            value={this.state.email}
                        />
                    </View>

                    <View style={{marginTop: 32}}>
                        <TextInput style={styles.input}
                            secureTextEntry 
                            autoCapitalize="none"
                            placeholder="Password"
                            onChangeText={password => this.setState({password})}
                            value={this.state.password}
                        />
                    </View>
                </View>

                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={this.handleLogin}>
                    <Text style={{ color: "#FFF", fontWeight: "500"}}>Log in</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Because you are not importing `TextInput` from `react-native`

Comment: Ah. I did not realise that I forgot to do that. Knew it was going to be something silly, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to import `TextInput` from react-native so you can use it in your code. Add it to your existing import statement like this:

```
import {View, Text, TextInput, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
```